# iPad AQGridView not showing my UIImages not in bundle

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I am using the ImageDemo template and it works great if I code in an image from the bundle but when I try and load them from directories I have created in my app I have no luck.

Code:

```
    - (AQGridViewCell *) gridView: (AQGridView *) aGridView cellForItemAtIndex: (NSUInteger) index
    {
        static NSString * PlainCellIdentifier = @"PlainCellIdentifier";

        AQGridViewCell * cell = nil;
        ImageDemoGridViewCell * plainCell = (ImageDemoGridViewCell *)[aGridView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: PlainCellIdentifier];
        if ( plainCell == nil )
        {
            plainCell = [[[ImageDemoGridViewCell alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 200.0, 150.0)
                                                      reuseIdentifier: PlainCellIdentifier] autorelease];
            plainCell.selectionGlowColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
        }
        NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@_tn.jpg",[manufacturerID stringValue], [[[self.collectionItems objectAtIndex:index] valueForKey:@"PhotoName"]  stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"%20"]];
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *savePath =[documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName] ;
        NSData *imageData = nil;
        BOOL fileExists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:savePath];
        if (fileExists) {
            imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:savePath];

        } else {
            NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"NoImageAvailableThumbNail" ofType:@"png"];
            imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];   
        }

UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
    NSLog(@"%@", myImage);
    if (myImage==nil) {
        NSLog(@"NO IMAGE");
    }
    plainCell.image = myImage;      

        cell = plainCell;

        return ( cell );
    }
```

I code I am using to pull the image data I know works because I use it all over in other places in my app and I am checking for nil when I set the property on the AQGridViewCell:

```
- (void) setImage: (UIImage *) anImage
{
    _imageView.image = anImage;
    [self setNeedsLayout];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see the check for a nil UIImage in your example there. Are you certain it's being loaded correctly? Try creating the image on one line and setting it on another so you can see it being created in the debugger. For reference, I do something similar with cached book cover images in the Kobo app, and that works. One difference though is that I use the C methods to load a UIImage from a PNG file. Something like UIImageFromPNGData(), off the top of my head (sorry replying by iPhone right now).

The only other thing I can think to check is whether the image view is hidden for some reason. Printing it in the debugger should tell you that, along with it's size, layout, etc.

Comment: thank you so much for answering, I added the logging and I definitely get an image: <UIImage: 0x6d30090> but they just don't show.  I must have done something silly somewhere - I'll keep looking and thanks.

Comment: still stuck on this, I know the UIImage is created and passed - I added them to the main view as it looped through as a test and they are definitely loaded.  I can load images included in the bundle just from no where else including from a URL.  If you can think of anything else it could be I would appreciate it - thanks for the help.

Comment: One thing to check would be that the image view's frame isn't an empty rect (i.e. width/height of 0.0). It should be getting updated in `-layoutSubviews`, so check there first. Also, check whether the returned UIImage has an empty or nil size (0.0x0.0) as that could cause the same sort of issue.